# using Json in Portable Class Library

Tags: c#, portable-class-library

I'm attempting to load some data in a portable class library. The data is in JSON format. I need parse and work with this information. Unfortunately, it doesn't appear that System.Json is available. At the same time, I tried to include the Json.Net NuGet package without any luck.

How does one work with JSON data in a portable class library?

Thank you

Comment: What was wrong with Json.NET?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Json.net pcl is available - if you can't find an official nuget version, then a slightly old version is in the mvvmcross json plugin package - or in the mvvmcross binaries git repo.

Answer (score 9):

JSON.NET ***is*** available in PCL, [check these release notes:](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2012/10/07/json-net-4-5-release-10-portable-class-library-on-nuget.aspx)

*Json.NET's major new feature this release is the portable class library assembly is available over NuGet. This is made possible by NuGet 2.1 supporting portable class libraries. Read more about NuGet 2.1 [here](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/release-notes/nuget-2.1).*

- Update `NuGet`
- [Get](http://json.codeplex.com/releases/view/95877) `JSON.NET`